# Find the intersection of two lists in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of int A,B. i like to do the following step in linq

```
list<int> c = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < a.count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < b.count; j++)
    {
        if (a[i] == b[j])
        {
            c.add(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

if its a and b is `object` , I need check particular properties like this manner and add list if it equals how can i do this in linq?

Comment: This code will return duplicates in c if there are duplicates in a or b. eg a = {1,2,2,3} and b = {2,2,4,6} will give c = {2,2,2,2}. Is this what you want or are your lists unique anyway so its not important? I ask just because the obvious linq answer will give c={2,2} as that is the intersection of the lists.

Comment: @Femaref: really? Ah, ok. At least my point still stands. I'm still not great at linq stuff like this. :)

Comment: That's not confined to LINQ. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_Theory) might be a good read for you.

Comment: The title is misleading. For anyone who found this page and actually want to compare two enumerables for equality Linq has a method called [SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal.aspx).

Answer (score 90):

You could use the `Intersect` method:

```
var c = a.Intersect(b);
```

This return all values both in a and b. However, position of the item in the list isn't taken into account.

Comment: To save a google for others who come across this, the opposite LINQ method is 'Except'.

Comment: OP's code doesn't take position into account either so that is not an issue - however OP's code does something quite unusual that [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) does not: for each distinct element **e** that exists in both `a` and `b`, **e** is added to `c` _**n** times_, where **n** = [the number of times **e** occurs in `a`] * [the number of times **e** occurs in `b`]. This is not an intersect at all, but maybe OP intended to make an intersect and just implemented it wrong?

Answer (score 16):

You can use [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx):

```
var a = new List<int>();
var b = new List<int>();

var c = a.Intersect(b);
```

Comment: Is it possible to set condition in the intersection?

Comment: Yes, there's an override that takes a second parameter, which you can use to compare the lists based on specific properties rather than the default property comparison operator.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 9):

Produce a list `c` containing all elements that are present in both lists `a` and `b`:

```
List<int> c = a.Intersect(b).ToList();
```

Answer (score 8):

The LINQ equivalent of your code is:

```
var c = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, a.Count)
        from j in Enumerable.Range(0, b.Count)
        where a[i] == b[j]
        select a[i];

var cList = c.ToList();
```

But it's much nicer to do:

```
var c = from aItem in a 
        join bItem in b on aItem equals bItem
        select aItem;

var cList = c.ToList();
```

But this doesn't filter duplicates. To filter duplicates *completely*, you can do:

```
var cList = a.Intersect(b).ToList();
```

If you want duplicates to show up as many times as they do in `b`, for example:

```
var aSet = new HashSet<int>(a);
var cList = b.Where(aSet.Contains)
             .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my version of intersection:

```
var a = new List<int>();
var b = new List<int>();

// intersection
var c = a.Where(x => b.Any(y => x == y)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

As Chris mentions in his comment on the original question, the sample code provided will return duplicates in list c (see his comment for details). Intersect will only return distinct values. To duplicate the behavior of the original sample code, try this:

```
var c = (from value in a
         where b.Contains(a)
         select a);
```

Comment: Is that even going to be the same? That won't return the value in a twice if it is in b twice will it?

Comment: Hmmm...not sure, and good point. I'll need to experiment with that to find out.