# How to search lines on text file in another text file

Tags: c#, text-files

I have 2 text files, and I want to read the files and determine if any lines in file1 exists in file2.

Each line in file1 contains a subset of the information in the lines of file2 (each line in file2 is more complete than file1). For example, the lines of file1 have columns (x,y,z) and lines of file2 have columns(x,y,z,w).

I want read file1 and for any lines of file1 that also exist in file2, I want to save that line of file2(x,y,z,w)

I wrote this code but this not give me any answer:

```
var f1Lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\test1.txt");
var f2LineInf1 = File.ReadLines(@"D:\test2.txt")
    .Where(line => f1Lines.Contains(line))
    .Select(line => line).ToList();

File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\result.txt", f2LineInf1);
```

My files are huge (6 millions record) and I want take result in the shortest possible time.

one line of text1:

```
memberID        productID   Date            Rating  
A1004AX2J2HXGL  B0007RT9LC  May 30, 2005    3
```

one line of text2 have above columns + title and body.

Comment: Speed being relative, 12million+ lines in flat files will pretty much not be "fast"

Comment: @AustinFrench ok. my first problem is  this code not give me any answer.

Comment: `Where` can't give you an answer because `line` in text2 has more text. You should do a string comparison. Can you post some example text from each file?

Comment: According to your problem statement, the lines in **test1.txt** contain a subset of those in **test2.txt**. If that's the case, then the statement `f1Lines.Contains(line)` will never be true

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ query to find if items in a list are contained in another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656582/linq-query-to-find-if-items-in-a-list-are-contained-in-another-list)

Comment: Alternative possible duplicate: [Find the intersection of two lists in linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065593/find-the-intersection-of-two-lists-in-linq)

Comment: @Rudy can you see my post. I Edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as written is checking to see if any line in `f1Lines` starts with the current line in `f2LineInf1`. Since we know that each line in the first file contains a subset of the lines in the second file, this will never be true.

What we really want to do is, for each line in the second file, see if there are any lines in the first file that match the beginning of the second file line.

This can be done by:

```
var f1Lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"f:\public\temp\temp1.txt");
var f2LineInf1 = File.ReadLines(@"f:\public\temp\temp2.txt")
    .Where(line => f1Lines.Any(line.StartsWith));

File.WriteAllLines(@"f:\public\temp\result.txt", f2LineInf1);
```

Comment: I want just lines from temp2 that exist in temp1. your code  in additional lines of temp2 that exist in temp1, return linesof temp2 that not exist in temp1. I dont want it

Comment: This code will give you only the lines from temp2 that begin with a line in temp1. That is what `f1Lines.Any(line.StartsWith)` means: Return this temp2 line if it starts with any line from `f1Lines`. You say *"it returns lines of temp2 that do not exist in temp1"*. Please take a look at one of those lines, and verify that there is no line in temp1 that matches the beginning of the line, or provide a small example of two files that reproduce the error you're seeing with this code. Is it possible there is some whitespace line in your temp1 that is getting matched?

Answer (score 1):

The other answer answers exactly and should be accepted, but here is another way with less LINQ.

```
var f1Lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\test1.txt").ToList();
var f2Lines = File.ReadLines(@"D:\test2.txt").ToList();
var result = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in f1Lines)
{
    var found = f2Lines.Where((line) => line.Contains(item)).FirstOrDefault();
    if (found != null)
    {
        result.Add(found);
    }
}

File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\result.txt", result);
```

Comment: This code for a small data set work well. but for my dataset give error out of memory. have any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `HashSet<string>` (not `List<string>` or `string[]`) as a temporary collection; something like this:

```
 // Hash set is a most efficient - O(1) - data stucture for Contains
 // When working with 1e6 records O(n)/O(1) choice does matter...
 HashSet<string> toFind = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadLines(@"D:\test1.txt"));

 File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\result.txt", File
   .ReadLines(@"D:\test2.txt") 
   .Where(line => toFind.Contains(line)));
```